# Given A number N conver it to 2 square form

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I have a number `N` i want to subtract  square of `x` from `N` , where x is any integer

```
Num = N-x*x
```

Such that `Num`  can be represent as square of two numbers.

```
i.e Num= a^2+b^2  where a and b are integers
```

As far as i know to represent a number summation of two square it's prime factor of form `4k+3` should occur even times.

But how to determine `x` in most efficient way ? 
i tried some random cases it's always possible to do so

Comment: `x` can be zero

Comment: What do you mean "as a square of two numbers"? Do you mean "as a sum of two squares", or something else? Also, if that _is_ what you mean, isn't your problem best phrased as "I want to write a given number as the sum of three squares"? In that case, try $7$.

Comment: what do you mean "NUM can be represent as square of two numbers"?